A Postgres 9.6 database broke after a power cycle, and restoring with backups did not fix issue
I have an old Ubuntu 14.04 server with an old PostgreSQL 9.6 database on it, and I was having issues with the server earlier so I power cycled it (bad idea in hindsight). It's currently running on a DigitalOcean VPS with weekly backups.
When I logged back in, I noticed that the status of the server was "down" and
root@server:/home/username# service postgresql status
9.6/main (port 5432): down

When I try starting it, I get this error:
root@server:/home/username# service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.6 database server    
 * Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@9.6-main.service failed to load: No such file 
   or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service' for details.
                                                                                                                 
[fail]
root@server:/home/username# systemctl status postgresql@9.6-main.service
postgresql@9.6-main.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

I've tried restoring from backups from 5, 12, 19, and 26 days ago, but I get the same error each time.
I also tried reinstalling Postgres 9.6, but it looks like the files used to update Ubuntu 14.04 are no longer hosted.
My site is well overdue for a migration, but I want to recover from this first.
